# Solutions to convert & export charts/tables generated from web app using HTML/Javascript to editable Powerpoint (.pptx, .ppt)?

Tags: java, javascript, charts, export, powerpoint

I am building a web app where the user will choose different options to generate tables, charts, graphs, etc. using a front-end interface built with HTML/CSS/Javascript. Once the user configures their tables/charts the app will render them and generate a JSON object that will be saved on the server using Java/Postgresql. Once the user has the table/chart they want, the app needs to let them export the table/chart and programmatically generate a Powerpoint .pptx or .ppt  file (as well as a few other formats like Excel, Word, PDF) that is fully editable (not just a static image).

I have looked at Apache POI which seems to have good support for Excel but from what I can tell it currently does not support the creation of fully functioning, editable pptx and ppt Powerpoint files (only produces non-editable images).

http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/index.html
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.poi.user/17749

Another possible option might be to build functionality using OpenXML that will allow the user to specify their table/charts options on the front-end using HTML/Javascript/JSON and have the Powerpoint files (or other Microsoft Office app formats) generated using Javascript as described here:

http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2012/08/02/working-with-open-xml-documents-using-javascript.aspx

I am trying to find any other possible solutions (preferably non-proprietary open source that would be compatiable with our stack HTML/Javascript/JSON/Java/Postgresql) that provide this functionality and would appreciate any advice or suggestions from anyone that might have experience in this area, has implemented a solution for this or could recommend any other possible solutions.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You mention POI, but did you see [HSLF and XLSF](http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/index.html)?

> HSLF provides a way to read, create or modify PowerPoint presentations. In particular, it provides:
>
> - api for data extraction (text, pictures, embedded objects, sounds)
> - usermodel api for creating, reading and modifying ppt files
>
> XSLF is the POI Project's pure Java implementation of the PowerPoint 2007 OOXML (.xlsx) file format. Whilst HSLF and XSLF provide similar features, there is not a common interface across the two of them at this time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer CHB. Yes I reviewed XSLF and HSLF in detail and unfortunately, based on comments from members of the Apache POI team and the documentation, from what I could tell they do not support creation of a native, editable pptx and/or ppt file. http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/creating-PPT-using-Java-td2335895.html

Comment: What I need is the ability to create PowerPoint charts in a native, editable pptx and/or ppt file. http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.poi.user/17749. If you have found a way to do this with POI could you please provide additional info? I was trying to see if anyone has found or come up with any other solutions alternatives to POI.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be to use [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org). However, this requires a substantial understanding of the powerpoint XML format. We are currently looking into the same problem and have found an OK working solution so far using the commercial Aspose libraries.

**UPDATE:** It looks like its not so hard to get good results within a day or two. Especially when using pre-built PPTX and XLSX files that are merely adapted and joined.